# Outputting A Multidimensional Array As A String

Tags: php, arrays, string, output

I've tried `implode()`, `array_column()` and a few others, but for some reason I just can't get the correct output to show.

In short, how can I output this array as a string? This is actually an output that will go into rows inside of a table, that's based on an API.

Code:

```
<td><?php
    $desc1 = file_get_contents("https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/market/batch?symbols=$symbol[$x]&types=news&filter=headline");  
    $desc1 = json_decode($desc1,TRUE); 
    foreach($desc1 as $key111 => $des1) {
        echo ($des1['news']);
    }   
?></td>
```

Example output from a `var_dump()` in a given table row:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in E:\XAMPP... on line (Echo line)

```
Arrayarray(1) {
    ["news"]=> array(10) { 
        [0]=> array(1) { 
            ["headline"]=> string(92) "Facebook VP says Russian meddling aimed to divide America and it's working 'incredibly well'"
        } 
        [1]=> array(1) { 
            ["headline"]=> string(66) "In wake of indictments, Facebook doubling security staff to 20,000"
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) like the following:

```
$array = [
    "news" => [ 
        [
            "headline" => "Facebook VP says Russian meddling aimed to divide America and it's working 'incredibly well'",
        ],
        [
            "headline" => "In wake of indictments, Facebook doubling security staff to 20,000"
        ]
    ]
];

echo implode(PHP_EOL, array_column($array['news'], 'headline'));
```

Here is [the demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ad4ffab40b8eb2b6880fd713c37ae931e91f3523).

Of course, in the HTML you can use `<br/>` instead of `PHP_EOL`, or format data whatever you like.

Comment: Thing is tho, the content is dynamically generated by the API. The content above was just posted as an example of output- there's much more. So in essence, I need to do what you did but it has to be done automatically vs manually inputting that output if you know what I mean. Appreciate the help!

Comment: @Frenzyy, usually API's build in such way that they return data in one confirmed format. For the sake of example, I used the data from var_dump. But this doesn't matter, as the array format should not change from call to call.

Comment: @Frenzyy, oh, I see what you mean. If you want to just copy/paste, you can change `$array` to `$des1`;)

Comment: Thank you! This does work exactly how I want it to. One more question if you don't mind. If I decide to add another variable, such as source, like this: $desc1 = file_get_contents("https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/market/batch?symbols=$symbol[$x]&types=news&filter=headline,source");  
     $desc1 = json_decode($desc1,TRUE); 
     foreach($desc1 as $key111 => $des1) {
        echo implode(PHP_EOL, array_column($des1['news'], 'headline', 'source'));
      }     What am I doing wrong because it just carries on displaying the same thing. Add another column somehow? Thanks again!

Comment: @Frenzyy, `array_column` takes as the third argument new index. So you will end up with an array of the same values, but instead of numeric indexes the values of `'source'` column will be used. But as `implode` operates only on values, you will end up with the same result. Try [this](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d6b98ee1d36999deab52cc2a5abfd4e8fb5f6ee6).

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood, first time doing something like this, so is there a way to add this 'source' too then or not? Because when I do what I show above, the result doesn't change. And also, is there a way to add a line break or something after each result? Thanks for taking the time to explain this.

Comment: @Frenzyy, please, see the link from the comment above (click on "this" word). You can use `<br/>` instead of `PHP_EOL`: `implode('<br/>', array_column($array['news'], 'headline'));`.

Comment: I actually ended up doing something very similar and was gonna ask if there's a more efficient way to do it but guess not! Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You have an array inside each $des1  so  try  accessing to the content eg:

```
foreach($desc1['news'] as $key111 => $des1) {
   echo $des1["headline"];
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately, that's not it- "Notice: Undefined index: headline"

Comment: answer updated .. try accessing to desc1['new'] in foreach and  $des1["headline"] inside foreach

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: news in E:\XAMPP\ on line 

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in E:\XAMPP\ on line 224

Comment: try show the exact var_dump($desc1 )   because looking to your sample should be an array  .

Comment: I thought so, not a problem, I did try it using 'news'. Either way, answer above but thanks for your help!